# Как правильно использовать NSUserDefaults для хранения времени?

Tags: ios, аудио, время, nsuserdefaults

У меня есть аудио плеер. С помощью `NSUserDefaults` я сохраняю время остановки аудио, чтобы после перегрузки пользователь мог продолжить прослушивание с места остановки в предыдущей сессии. Проблема в том, что если я нажимаю кнопку плей и передвигаю ползунок вручную, время сохраняется. А если нажимаю кнопку плей и ползунок двигается сам, время не сохраняется. Почему?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if (_index == 0) {
self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
[self setupAudioPlayer:@"1"];

}
else if (_index == 1) {
self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
[self setupAudioPlayer:@"2"];
}
else if (_index == 2) {
self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
[self setupAudioPlayer:@"3"];
}
}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return NO;
}


- (void)setupAudioPlayer:(NSString*)fileName
{

NSString *fileExtension = @"mp3";

[self.audioPlayer initPlayer:fileName fileExtension:fileExtension];
self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];


self.timeElapsed.text = @"0:00";

self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                      [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]]];
_currentTimeSlider.value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"time6"];
_timeElapsed.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"time5"];
[self setCurrentTime:self];
//[self playAudioPressed:_playButton];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
}

- (IBAction)playAudioPressed:(id)playButton
{


[self.timer invalidate];
if (!self.isPaused) {
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_pause.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

    [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
    self.isPaused = TRUE;



} else {
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
    self.isPaused = FALSE;
}

}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {


if (!self.scrubbing) {
    self.currentTimeSlider.value = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
}
self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                      [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

if (![self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
    self.isPaused = FALSE;

}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:_currentTimeSlider.value forKey:@"time6"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_timeElapsed.text forKey:@"time5"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (IBAction)setCurrentTime:(id)scrubber {
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];

[self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value];
self.scrubbing = FALSE;


}


- (IBAction)userIsScrubbing:(id)sender {
self.scrubbing = TRUE;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: потому, что когда вы двигаете ползунок, вы сохраняете время воспроизведения, а когда аудио играет, вы сохраняете текст из label. соответственно и с загрузкой то же самое - то, что вы загрузили текст и присвоили значение в label никакого воздействия на плеер не имеет

Comment: Изменил код. Добавил `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:_currentTimeSlider.value forKey:@«time6»];`

 

          `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`  в `updateTime` 

Теперь время, как и ожидалось, не сохраняется при перемещении ползунка вручную. Каким способом можно выполнить задачу корректно? Чтобы все работало нормально.

Comment: вам надо сохранять и загружать `currentAudioTime`, все остальное вы можете высчитать из этого. и сохранять по 100 раз за секунду тоже не надо - сохраняйте только когда плеер сворачивается (например, когда пользователь сворачивает приложение, или переходит на предыдущий экран)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в таймере у вас repeats:NO, следовательно таймер срабатывает один раз и останавливается. Вообще лучше всего сохранять время не по таймеру а по факту остановки проигрывания, сворачивания приложения или ухода с формы, смотря что Вам больше подходит